# Problem with nth-child, it does not respecting the name of the class

Tags: css

I would like to understand why the nth-child(even) it is getting the first element? I use .section just to get the div that have this class, but it is taking all elements.

```
.section:nth-child(even), .fernandoclass:nth-child(even){
  color:red
}
```

I created a PEN to try to show you guys what is happening:

https://codepen.io/fernandocacavaio/pen/gOMJoxE

**UPDATE:** I create a CodePen to show exactly what I am trying to do, I have two different type of PANEL on my page, and I am using row-reverse between them to one start with the image on right side, the next one will have the image on left side...

However in this new CodePen (https://codepen.io/fernandocacavaio/pen/vYKEXPo). I have one div with class testfernando and this DIV is breaking my logic to row-reverse. If you delete this DIV, you will noticed that the next panel will respect the row-reverse.

Answer (score 1):

You used `:nth-child()` instead of `:nth-of-type()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

> The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

> The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches elements of a given type (tag name), based on their position among a group of siblings.

Sample to see the different between both pseudo-selectors :

```css
.section:nth-child(even), .fernandoclass:nth-child(even){
  color:red
}
.section:nth-of-type(even), .fernandoclass:nth-of-type(even){
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="alo">
  fafsaadsadsadsada
</div>

<section class="section">
  <div class="sectioninside">
    afee
  </div>
 </section>

<div id="alo">
  fafsaadsadsadsada
</div>

<div id="alo">
  fafsaadsadsadsada
</div>

<section class="section">
  <div class="sectioninside">
    afee
  </div>
</section>

<div class="fernandoclass">
  fernando
</div>

<section class="section">
  <div class="sectioninside">
    afee
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <div class="sectioninside">
    afee
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: the problem I need to intercalate between this two classes (.section and .fernandoclass)

Ex:
```
fafsaadsadsadsada
afee
fafsaadsadsadsada
fafsaadsadsadsada
afee              <------- GET THIS
fernando
afee              <--------GET THIS
afee
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added selectors in HTML comments after each HTML element so you can see what is going on here. Your selectors are working correctly.

The most important thing to bear in mind is that neither `id`, nor `class` nor `attribute selector` nor anything else will affect the `nth-of-type` number.

The only thing the `nth-of-type` number is counting is ***element type***.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.section:nth-of-type(even),
.fernandoclass:nth-of-type(even){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="alo"> <!-- #alo:nth-of-type(1) -->
  fafsaadsadsadsada
</div>

<section class="section"> <!-- .section:nth-of-type(1) -->
  <div class="sectioninside">
    afee
  </div>
 </section>

<div id="alo"> <!-- #alo:nth-of-type(2) -->
  fafsaadsadsadsada
</div>

<div id="alo"> <!-- #alo:nth-of-type(3) -->
  fafsaadsadsadsada
</div>

<section class="section"> <!-- .section:nth-of-type(2) -->
  <div class="sectioninside">
    afee
  </div>
</section>

<div class="fernandoclass"> <!-- .fernandoclass:nth-of-type(4) -->
  fernando
</div>

<section class="section"> <!-- .section:nth-of-type(3) -->
  <div class="sectioninside">
    afee
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section"> <!-- .section:nth-of-type(4) -->
  <div class="sectioninside">
    afee
  </div>
</section>

<div class="fernandoclass"> <!-- .fernandoclass:nth-of-type(5) -->
  fernando
</div>

<div class="fernandoclass"> <!-- .fernandoclass:nth-of-type(6) -->
  fernando
</div>
```

Comment: I want to the classes .fernandoclass and .section intercalate between them as well.